# Generic typescript component inherit component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I am using Typescript and I would like to have prop validation on a generic component. I would like to create a Field component which renders a label, an error message and a component which is passed as a prop. I had multiple attempts to make it work but one part or the other fails either way. I've also read through dozens of articles but I couldn't find anyone facing the exactly same issue.

This is what I've got so far:

```
interface IFieldProps<P> {
    is: React.ComponentType<P>;
}

class Field<P> extends React.PureComponent<IFieldProps<P>> {
    render() {
        const { is, ...rest } = this.props;

        const Component = is;

        return (
            <div>
                <Component {...rest} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

interface ITextInputProps {
    value: string
}

class TextInput extends React.PureComponent<ITextInputProps> {
    render() {
        return (
            <input {...this.props} />
        );
    }
}

const render = () => <Field is={TextInput} />;
```

The typescript compiler is not yelling about that the prop `value` is missing in the `render` method, So I will make the `IFieldProps` to extend from `P` and that should make it work:

```
interface IFieldProps<P> extends P {
    is: React.ComponentType<P>;
}
```

The compiler now says that "An interface may only extend a class or another interface".
Okay, then I will make this a type, no worries:

```
type IFieldProps<P> = P & {
    is: React.ComponentType<P>;
}
```

Now everything is screwed up. It yells on `...rest` that "Rest types may only be created from object types". It yells on `<Component />` that "JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures". And finally it yells on `<Field />` that `value` prop is missing - and in the meantime the autocomplete on the props stops working in vscode.
I thought that if I would have some constraints on P (e.g. `P extends {}`) that would fix some of the issues, but it didn't.

How can I make a generic component that inherits the props of a component passed as a prop? Is still something overcomplicated? How other people solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It works when wrapped component props are kept in another prop (as opposed to being mixed with `is`):

```
interface IFieldProps<P> {
  is: React.ComponentType<P>;
  props: P;
};

class Field<P> extends React.PureComponent<IFieldProps<P>> {
  render() {
      const { is, props } = this.props;

      const Component = is;

      return (
          <div>
              <Component {...props} />
          </div>
      );
  }
}

interface ITextInputProps {
  readonly value: string;
}

class TextInput extends React.PureComponent<ITextInputProps> {
  render() {
      return (
          <input {...this.props} />
      );
  }
}

const render = () => <Field is={TextInput} props={{ value: ''} } />;
```

I wasn't able to find the source of the error based on the message:

> Type 'Pick &
>   Readonly>, "children" | Exclude>' is not
>   assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   LibraryManagedAttributes["is"], P & { children?:
>   ReactNode; }>'.   Type 'Pick &
>   Readonly>, "children" | Exclude>' is not
>   assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes["is"], P &
>   { children?: ReactNode; }>'.

Comment: I also thought about this solution however it looks weird to me that I have to modify the API of my components just because I am using Typescript. I am also afraid that this would force the PureComponents to re-render because the `props` would change in every render. I would like to use this pattern for my buttons/links as well like `<Button onClick={this.doThat}>Submit</Button>` and `<Button is={Link} to="/somewhere"}>Redirect me</Button>` without modifying the API.

Comment: I agree. However, I have a feeling this has more to do with React type definitions rather than TypeScript itself. When I was trying to make it work without changing your desired API, what helped was using the type parameter on the call side (`const render = () => <Field<ITextInputProps> is={TextInput} value="foo"  />`) — but the type of the wrapped component (`is`) was still inferred incorrectly.